# How to post comment reply on a specific post in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, comments, reply

I am new to iOS programming and I just want to know that how can we reply on a specific post?

I have read a lot of links but I can't get the point.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments

I have use this method but it is not working properly this code update/edit your post or comment:

```
-(void) abc
{
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/YOUR_POST_ID/comments"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              /* handle the result */
                              NSLog(@"Results == %@",result);
                              NSLog(@"error == %@",error);
                          }];
}
```

and plus I am calling this method into my textfield

```
[myReplyingUITextField addTarget:self action:@selector(abc) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `message` parameter to your API call. Pass the comment into this parameter and you'll be able to comment on the post. See the [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/).